# Choerent header-counter on all sub-pages #jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi just a general question (don't have any code for this):
is it possible to make counter that is effected by actions on different pages?
For example, If I have a header with a counter, and on each sub-page there is a button "A", the value will be added when the button is pressed on each page, and the value that is displayed in the header is coherent on all pages.

Comment: You could do this with AJAX where your pages sent a count to the server and then any page could pull the count.

Comment: I see, so this would demand a server then (I wouldn't be able to try it locally that is). And how is this done? I am such a code n00b!

Comment: I suppose you could also try to do this with cookies and JavaScript as well.

Comment: Yes I'm trying it out right know, with the jQuery .cookies plug-in but cant seem to get it to work